# OBIEE 'binning' aggregation without including lowest dimension

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, obiee

I have a fact/dim combination in OBIEE that looks something like this:

```
Order_number, Order_Quantity

1234, 150
2345, 80
3456, 20
4567, 50
```

What I would like to do is create a report that aggregates the total number of orders with quantities in the defined 'bins'. For example, there are 3 orders with less than 100 quantity, and one with greater than 100:

```
Quantity_Bin, # Orders

>100, 1
<100, 3
```

I can do this quite easily using a 'CASE WHEN' statement and a pivot table, however **that requires me to include the 'order_number' field on the report**. The problem is that table has 1 million+ rows, which are all returned to the presentation server even though they aren't displayed on the report. Can I specify obiee to do this calculation/aggregation without returning a row for every order_number?

Comment: Where will you count orders with quantity exactly 100?

Answer (score 0):

Already responded on the OTN forums...